# Issue Getting a Mass Name change .bat on a share to add spaces to the new file name

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd, rename

I know someone out there has a nice quick solution for this: I just believe I am missing something. I am slightly new to creating bat files. I have roughly 2,000 files with improper naming on a share drive.

The below bat gets me started but I need to have the new file name include spaces but when I try it gives an invalid syntax command even with the ' " '.

Line 3, 3.MRF, is where it is giving me the syntax error '-' is not a valid command.

```
@echo
forfiles /S /M "1.PURCHASE*.*" /C "cmd /c rename "1.PURCHASE*.*" "2.PURCHASE*.*""
forfiles /S /M "3.MRF*.*" /C "cmd /c rename "3.MRF*.*" "1.MRF - *.*""
forfiles /S /M "3.ACOMRF-*.*" /C "cmd /c rename "3.ACOMRF-*.*" "1.ACO-MRF-*.*""
forfiles /S /M "2.RECEIPT*.*" /C "cmd /c rename "2.RECEIPT*.*" "3.RECEIPT*.*""
forfiles /S /M "2.RECIEPT*.*" /C "cmd /c rename "2.RECIEPT*.*" "3.RECEIPT*.*""
:exit
@pause
```

Comment: Correct but the only issues I have noticed so far are the issues with the spelling of receipt from the language barrier at some sites and MRF not having the ' - ' after it. This is a good exercise to show my boss why I told him years ago that we should use underscores instead of spaces. haha

Comment: Why are you using `forfiles` in the first place? `forfiles` doesn't make sense at all, when you don't use it's `@` parameters (not that you'd need them)

Comment: @Stephan Just did some simple Googling came across it to find the files within sub-directories. I am super new to batch files but in the process of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps run a `for` loop instead, it just looks much better to start off with:

```
@echo off
for /r /d %%a in (*) do (
    pushd "%%~a"
    ren "1.PURCHASE*.*" "2.PURCHASE*.*"
    ren "3.MRF*.*" "1.MRF - *.*"
    ren "3.ACOMRF-*.*" "1.ACO-MRF-*.*"
    ren "2.RECEIPT*.*" "3.RECEIPT*.*"
    ren "2.RECIEPT*.*" "3.RECEIPT*.*"
    popd
)
```

Here you need one loop that will pushd to each of the subdirectories, rename anything that matches the rename parameter.

Comment: This works perfectly! Tested on about 100 files and they all changed just like I need them to. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) within a simple [for-loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FOR %%A IN (3.MRF*.*) DO (
    SET name=%%A
    rename "!name!" "!name:3.MRF=1.MRF - !"
)
```

Before:

```
3.MRF A.txt
3.MRF B.txt
3.MRF C.txt
```

After:

```
1.MRF -  A.txt
1.MRF -  B.txt
1.MRF -  C.txt
```

## Update

Made a more generic solution which lets you define all search and replace strings. Moreover it works on all subdirs now.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

PUSHD "%0\.."

REM <search_1>;<replace_1|<search_2>;<replace_2>|...|<search_n>;<replace_n>
SET SearchAndReplace=3.MRF - ~1.MRF - ;3.ACOMRF-~1.ACO-MRF-
REM Replace ; with \n
SET SearchAndReplace=!SearchAndReplace:;=^

!

REM iterate over search and replace tokens
FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims=~" %%G IN ("!SearchAndReplace!") DO (
  set search=%%G
  set replace=%%H
  FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN (`dir /S /B /A:-d "*!search!*" 2^>nul`) do (
    set file="%%I"
    REM hack to allow replace !replace! for !search! in !file!
    FOR /F "delims=" %%J IN ("!search!") do (
      FOR /F "delims=" %%K IN ("!replace!") do (
        echo move !file! !file:%%J=%%K!
        move !file! !file:%%J=%%K!
      )
    )
  )
)

POPD
```

Set the `SearchAndReplace` variable as needed (see comment).

Comment: I am very new to batch files but I will be reading up on the links you provided. It only works in the directory that I place the bat file and not sub-directories. Also, it renames the '3.MRF - P2.pdf' to '1.MRF -  - P2.pdf'

Comment: @brandoncreasap Your question doesn't mention subfolders but you may use `FOR /R` for recursion. Beware that that the accepted solution won't work for files with only one dot. `ren "3_MRF*.*" "1.MRF - *.*"` leads to `3_MRF - P2.pdf => 1.MRF -`